# Possibility to only get one nested object from another nested object

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have an index with shop orders. Each document represents one order. In short my mapping looks like this:

```
{
 "properties": {
  "id": {
        "type": "keyword"
  },
  "shopid": {
        "type": "keyword"
  }, 
  "orderarticles": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
      "orderid": {"type": "keyword"},
      "artid": {"type": "keyword"},
      "categories": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "catid": {"type": "keyword"},
          "pos": {"type": "integer"}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to get only the category with the smallest pos value, per orderarticle

Any Idea how to get those ?

I tried with a construct of nested and reverse nested aggregations but this did not brought me a solution.

Maybe I just need a hint :-)

EDIT:
Sample Doc:

```
"_source" : {
      "id" : "0461a3310615643a1ffb4e3842c10c66",
      "shopid" : "2",
      "userid" : "ef7316c9f9cf3d12143aae63c43401c2",
      "orderdate" : "2020-05-19T18:53:19+02:00",
      "ordernr" : "999999",
      "ramandantid" : "1",
      "billemail" : "test@test.de",
      "billcountryid" : "a7c40f631fc920687.20179984",
      "delcountryid" : "",
      "totalnetsum" : "132",
      "delcost" : "11.9",
      "discount" : "0",
      "currency" : "EUR",
      "currate" : "1",
      "orderarticles" : [
        {
          "orderid" : "0461a3310615643a1ffb4e3842c10c66",
          "artid" : "47eaed3db45b3685b58f70fdfc5d70dd",
          "artnum" : "60.0605.8",
          "title" : "Test Article",
          "amount" : "3",
          "pic1" : "r6006058-01.jpg",
          "nprice" : "44",
          "netprice" : "132",
          "convertedtotalnetprice" : "132",
          "convertednetprice" : "44",
          "categories" : [
            {
              "catid" : "085328abacf9366f60728bff31a310df",
              "pos" : "75"
            },
            {
              "catid" : "8c7e45d5fc6bdde76deaeca4f4eabbb9",
              "pos" : "14"
            },
            {
              "catid" : "73afd2bd79791f9761731c2e157e06c1",
              "pos" : "37"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "billcountryisoalpha2" : "DE",
      "billcountrytitle" : "Germany",
      "delcountryisoalpha2" : null,
      "delcountrytitle" : null,
      "exchangerate" : 1,
      "convertedtotalnetsum" : "132"
    }
  }
    "_source" : {
      "id" : "0461a3310615643a1ffb4e3842c10c66",
      "shopid" : "2",
      "userid" : "ef7316c9f9cf3d12143aae63c43401c2",
      "orderdate" : "2020-05-19T18:53:19+02:00",
      "ordernr" : "999999",
      "ramandantid" : "1",
      "billemail" : "test@test.de",
      "billcountryid" : "a7c40f631fc920687.20179984",
      "delcountryid" : "",
      "totalnetsum" : "132",
      "delcost" : "11.9",
      "discount" : "0",
      "currency" : "EUR",
      "currate" : "1",
      "orderarticles" : [
        {
          "orderid" : "0461a3310615643a1ffb4e3842c10c66",
          "artid" : "47eaed3db45b3685b58f70fdfc5d70dd",
          "artnum" : "60.0605.8",
          "title" : "Test Article",
          "amount" : "3",
          "pic1" : "r6006058-01.jpg",
          "nprice" : "156",
          "netprice" : "132",
          "convertedtotalnetprice" : "132",
          "convertednetprice" : "44",
          "categories" : [
            {
              "catid" : "another category id",
              "pos" : "75"
            },
            {
              "catid" : "8c7e45d5fc6bdde76deaeca4f4eabbb9",
              "pos" : "14"
            },
            {
              "catid" : "another category id",
              "pos" : "37"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "orderid" : "0461a3310615643a1ffb4e3842c10c66",
          "artid" : "another article id",
          "artnum" : "60.0605.7",
          "title" : "Test Article 2",
          "amount" : "3",
          "pic1" : "r6006058-01.jpg",
          "nprice" : "200",
          "netprice" : "600",
          "convertedtotalnetprice" : "600",
          "convertednetprice" : "200",
          "categories" : [
            {
              "catid" : "another category id",
              "pos" : "10"
            },
            {
              "catid" : "8c7e45d5fc6bdde76deaeca4f4eabbb9",
              "pos" : "100"
            },
            {
              "catid" : "another category id",
              "pos" : "37"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "billcountryisoalpha2" : "DE",
      "billcountrytitle" : "Germany",
      "delcountryisoalpha2" : null,
      "delcountrytitle" : null,
      "exchangerate" : 1,
      "convertedtotalnetsum" : "132"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Got a few sample docs + an example of the desired result?

Comment: I edited my question and added an sample doc.
My goal is to calculate the total revenue of a category. Therefore i need the nprice of the orderarticle. But only for the category with the lowest pos. To avoid that an article is counted twice. In this Example the article should only "match" for category with pos = 14.
I hope you understand what i want to archieve.

Comment: I see. So what would be the desired `nprice`? 44? Do you have 2 or 3 more docs with maybe more than 1 `orderarticles`? Or does that not play a role here?

Comment: Yes I updated the example by another doc with two `orderarticles`.  In the first doc only the category with id `8c7e45d5fc6bdde76deaeca4f4eabbb9` should match.
In the second doc only the first `orderarticle`  should match for this category. Because in the second this category has a higher `pos` value.
So the `sum of nprice` for this category should be 44 + 156.
Thanks for investigating